# Syntax highlighting in ExtJS?

Tags: extjs, syntax-highlighting, bespin

Does anybody know of an ExtJS editor (like HTMLEditor) with syntax highlighting or does someone has some experience integrating Bespin or other Scripts into it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no specific editor for ExtJS code highlighting, however, you can use [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) for Javascript code highlighting. Even I integrated it with my ExtJS application to write Javascript as well as ExtJS codes and it is working perfectly.

If you want to get this feature for highlighting codes in IDE then you can use Spket Update : "http://www.spket.com/update/"  in Eclipse (Help->Software Updates->Find and Install->Search for new feeatures) for ExtJS code highlighting.

Answer (score 2):

you could use [ace-extjs](https://github.com/cadorn/ace-extjs)

Answer (score 0):

In the ExtJs Forum someone published a [syntax file for vim](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?75458-Vim-Syntax-Highlighting-for-Ext&p=363156), which I use daily.

There is also this (older) blog post : [IDEs, Plugins and tool for ExtJs](http://www.sencha.com/blog/2008/02/01/ides-plugins-and-tools-for-ext-js-20/).

Finally, you have a lot of [forums thread abouts IDE](http://www.google.com/search?hl=fr&q=site%3Awww.extjs.com+ide).

Answer (score -1):

PHP Storm and Webstorm are great